# Different usage of the structure "wonder / was wondering"

Tags: grammar, american-english

Could you please let me know which one of the structure "wonder / was wondering" is more in common use in AE speech:

> **1)** **I wonder if / whether**
>
> used to ask politely for something [= may I]:
>
> - I wonder if I might have a drink?

---

> **2)** **I was wondering if / whether**
>
> **a)** used to politely ask someone to help you:
>
> - I was wondering if I could borrow your car?
>
> **b)** used to ask someone politely if they would like to do something:
>
> - I was wondering if you’d like to come to dinner.

**Source:** *Longman Dictionary.*
I guess the only common usage in today's speech is '2a'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***2a*** is the most used. ***2b*** is used frequently as well.

***1*** isn't really used in the context of asking for something like a drink or a ride, etc.

However, ***1*** is used more for telling someone else that they have a thought about something, but it's assumed that the other person should answer what their thought/question is if they know. Like "*I wonder how those big fluffy clouds form?*".

Comment: I agree that ***1*** isn't terribly common, but I'm not sure I'd go so far as "isn't really used." I don't think the drink example is a particularly good one, but I don't see much difference in meaning between ***1*** and ***2a***. _I was wondering if I might borrow your car_ could be regarded as "asking for something" as much as it is "asking for someone to help you." _I wonder if I could make a reservation for tomorrow night_: Is that asking for _help_, or asking for _something_? It's a fuzzy dividing line.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of 2):

> I **was wondering** if I could borrow your car?
>   I **was wondering** if you’d like to come to dinner.

this is basically an indirect way of requesting a favor. This is polite and makes no assumption that it will be accepted.

In the case of 1):

> I **wonder** if I might have a drink?

This really needs more context or another example. It seems like something you might say to yourself:

> I **wonder** if I am losing my mind.

not something you would say to someone else.

Both are normal usage but different.